# Replacing English sentences in program dialogues with Bulgarian translations results in text truncation

Tags: encoding, embedded-resource

I have a very old program (written in the time of Windows XP in C++, I trust). I need to translate certain dialogues of the program from English to Bulgarian. In principle, this can be done via resource file editing. It works just fine with one serious exception. It is only the first half of Bulgarian phrases that is shown after editing, compiling and saving the resource. I realise it has everything to do with encodings (probably, CP1252 is replaced with UTF-8 somehow).

I tried to use software called Resource hacker as well as MS Visual studio to edit the resource, but the problem persists in both cases. Please give me ideas on how this problem can be solved. I am no programmer in any way, so please don't be too laconic :-).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I read the document you cited, but I don't understand what exactly I should edit. I described the problem as clearly as I could. Not sure what I can add.

Comment: Is there an *external*  resource file where dialogues are saved? In any case, share at least some examples of original, translated and truncated sentences (exactly in corresponding triplets, please)… If possible, share _structure_ of such a resource in question (maybe _index + text + terminator_, or _index + length + text_, or…?